# Similarity, Relatedness and Association

Tags: computational-linguistics

From the NLP point of view. what are the major differences between words synonym, similarity, relatedness and association. With examples if possible. Thank you

Answer (score 2):

Synonymy means two words have the same meaning. An example would be words that are in the same [WordNet](https://wordnet.princeton.edu/) synset. It should be noted that WordNet is word-sense disambiguated, meaning words with multiple meanings are represented as completely separate entities.

Similarity measures the extent to which two words share meaning. For example, path similarity, Wu-Palmer similarity, and Leacock-Chodorow similarity all compute the similarity between WordNet synsets using the paths between them in WordNet's is-a heirarchy. If two words are in the same synset (i.e. they are synonyms), their similarity is generally 1. You can play around with these similarity scorers using [NLTK's WordNet implementation](http://www.nltk.org/howto/wordnet.html).

Another common type of similarity is word embedding (Word2Vec, GloVe, etc.) similarity. This is generally computed as the cosine similarity between each word's vectors. In generally, word embeddings follow the [distributional hypothesis](https://aclweb.org/aclwiki/Distributional_Hypothesis) that similar words occur in similar contexts. This means what you're actually measuring is subsitutability. For example, any sentence where you use the word "dog" (as in the animal), you can substitute it with the word "puppy". Thus "dog" and "puppy" are similar. Interestingly, this means that word pairs like "white" and "black" are also very similar according to word embeddings, [even though humans generally consider them opposites](https://medium.com/@timsears/the-opposite-of-hitler-5eb570346020).

I personally consider relatedness and association to be the same thing. Relatedness encompasses similarity but is much broader. Similarity measures the degree to which two words are the same, e.g. "dog" and "canine" describe the same concept. However, "leash" and "dog" are very different. One is an animal while the other is a long, thin, strong piece of cord or fabric. However, "leash" and "dog" are very related because dogs often are walked on leashes. Examples of related measures are less common but still exist. Good places to start are [Extended Lesk](http://www.d.umn.edu/~tpederse/Pubs/ijcai03.pdf) and [Gloss Vectors](https://pdfs.semanticscholar.org/ef93/f02b1dc8be3779763cf99a9ed7d192809ea2.pdf). Both are implemented as part of the [WordNet::Similarity](http://wn-similarity.sourceforge.net/) Perl library.

If I may self-promote, I'm actually developing a semantic relatedness measure based on word associations and I've seen some encouraging results on a [humour recognition task](http://www.aclweb.org/anthology/W16-4308). I've also developed an [association strength prediction model](http://www.aclweb.org/anthology/D17-1132).